# How do I send only one notification to a user in a Database listener in Firebase Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

The app concept is simple, I track the price of a certain item, and push a notification whenever a users desired price point is hit.

The Price of the item (**ActualPrice**) is reflected through a Firebase Realtime Database field that is updated ever few seconds.

The users and their requested prices (**RequestedPrice**), as it stands, is saved in Firestore documents, each with two fields:

1. Price
2. FCM Token

The token is an FCM token to push notifications to devices.

In Firebase Cloud Functions, I have a listener that triggers whenever the **ActualPrice** changes, which is every few seconds, through the `.onWrite()` function. It then cross compares all the users prices, and pushes notifications only to the ones that have their **RequestedPrice** met.

The issue is that, this event is triggered frequently, so users that have their prices met keep receiving notifications ever few seconds.

One idea I had is to add a field to users Firestore documents, and update it whenever the user has already received the notification or not yet. The only issue is that you can not alter document fields through Firebase Functions.

If you have any ideas I would very much appreciate them.

---

Edit:

```
const UIDRef = db.collection("/Currency/UserIDs");
const snapshot = await UIDRef.where("Price", ">=", RTDPrice).get();

snapshot.forEach(doc => {
          const Temp = {
            Status: 'Los Angeles',
          };
          doc.set(Temp);
```

Comment: " The only issue is that you can not alter document fields through Firebase Functions." Why not? That actually sounds like the solution I would go for, either storing the information of who you already notified in the document, or in Realtime Database.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen As far as I'm aware you can only add documents through ".add", there is no function to add a field to an existing document.

Comment: ```.add()``` applies to **COLLECTIONS**, you're looking for ```docRef.set(data, {mergeoption:true})```, ```docRef.update(data)``` which apply to DOCUMENTS - https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference

Comment: ```const UIDRef = db.collection("/Currency/UserIDs");``` ```const snapshot = await UIDRef.where("Price", ">=", RTDPrice).get();``` ```snapshot.forEach(doc => { docs.set({Temp: 'Sent'}, {mergeoption:true}); });``` I've tried implementing this, although I'm not sure where I went wrong. @LeadDreamer

Comment: What if you do `doc.update(Temp)`, in the code in your question instead?

Comment: ```.forEach()``` is NOT ASYNCHRONOUS - you need ```Promise.all(snapshot.map())```

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I've managed to figure it out, the missing part was `ref` between the `doc.update(Temp)`, so it would be `doc.ref.update(Temp)`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to maintain the last 'sent' status in each user with their FCM. using a secondary condition, you can query if the date is older than the current threshold.
Once you send a message to that user, you simply update the current timestamp to the database through the admin sdk

1. Price
2. FCM token
3. lastNotified

References:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#writing-triggered_functions
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data#node.js
- https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#node.js

Comment: That was the idea, but figuring out how to add/update a field for an existing document was the challenge. I've edited the question and added a snippet of code that I'm not sure why isn't working.

Comment: is that collection/document path literal? if so, that would be your problem.

Comment: Any updates? to clarify my earlier comment, you can't query from a document path, it must be resolved from a collection path.

Comment: The issue ended up being that I wasn't using `ref` to alter the "doc" data. So instead of: `doc.ref.update` I was using `doc.update`